# Policy based authentication taking into account what resources an user can work on?

Tags: asp.net-core, authorization

I have setup my web api to use policy based authorization. I can have permissions like invoice:list, invoice:edit, invoice:delete, order:list, order:edit and so on.

Now, I need to return different sets of data depending on the user that is logged in. For example an user can retrieve all invoices (sales manager for example) and others just the ones created by them.

Would it be a good way to do it, add a bit more information to the claim like -> inovice:list:all, invoice:list:own, etc...? And add differnt filters to the final query depending on the "all" or "own" part?

What other alternatives can be implemented to solve this problem?

Cheers.

Comment: No. [Claims are not permissions](https://leastprivilege.com/2016/12/16/identity-vs-permissions/). Your option is to implement it yourself. Take the ID (`sub` claim) from your token and use that to load permissions from your database and base your logic base on it (and some Acl service you code yourself)

Comment: Don't really follow you. I think I have what you suggest. When a user login in my webapi, they pass through a middleware that gets the permissions from the database and inserts them as claims of the httpContext.User.Identity. Then, I authorize users using the ussual "[Authorize(Policy = XXXXX)]",These policies are for example InvocieList, InvoiceEdit, etc. Now I want to add a new layer of authorization having some users to see its own resources and others too see all.

Comment: My question is if it is ok to expand these policies to something lik InvoiceListAll, InvoiceListOwn, etc. to accomplish this or is it too verbose or have some other problems I can't foresee